# Getting the sum for loop factorial

Tags: c, loops, sum, factorial

Could I please get advice.
I am trying to get the sum of the values labelled 'calculation'.
My code is currently outputting the values for every pass through the loop but I would just like 1 value which is the sum of all these values.

Thank you for your advice in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i, f = 1;
float calculation = 0;
int main() 
{
    for (i = 1; i <= 19; i++) 
    {
        f = f * i;
        //printf("Factorial of %d is: %d\n",i,f);// just for me to check//
        calculation = 1.00 / f;
        printf("Factorial calculation is %d! = %f\n", i, calculation);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to know how to do factorial, but you are stuck on addition? Side note, does your factorial actually work okay? That should be `unsigned long long f;` or `uint64_t f;` otherwise there is integer overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Barmak. I had previously used the '+=' to attempt to store the sum of the calculation as it went through the loop, similar to the answer below, but it just wasn't working for some reason. I'm thought perhaps there was another way I should be doing it. I'm very new to coding, apologies. Thank you for the tip on the variable assignment.

Comment: Change to `unsigned long long f;` and `printf("Factorial of %d is: %llu\n",i,f)` (un-comment it) then it should print result consistent with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store a sum value for every calculation in the for loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i, f = 1;
float calculation = 0;
int main() 
{
    for (i = 1; i <= 19; i++) 
    {
        f = f * i;
        //printf("Factorial of %d is: %d\n",i,f);// just for me to check//
        calculation += 1.00 / f;
    }
    printf("Factorial calculation is %d! = %f\n", i, calculation);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you Nguyễn Ngọc Hùng Long. I had tried using '+=' for the calculation variable, but for some reason I just couldn't get it to work so I thought I must have been doing something else wrong.

Comment: @StephNolan can you please share your code?
Mine worked fine, I checked the code on
https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/